# Netbeans modules dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans, dependencies

Suppose that I have three interfaces: Interface1, Interface2 that extends Interface1 and Interface3 that extends Interface2. 
Interface1 is located in the module1
Interface2 is located in the module2
Interface3 is located in the module3

My question is how can I configure module1 and module2 to avoid that module3 requires the module1 to be build ?

Here a diagram for more details 
[image]

PS: Now I got the following error:

```
error: cannot access Interface1
public interface Interface3 extends Interface2{
  class file for module1.Interface1 not found
```

Comment: "Interface 3 that extends interface 3"

Comment: "Interface3 extends Interface2 "
Sorry :(

Comment: I can see that in the code sample, but I was posting the comment so you could edit it to make the question clearer, I'm not able to make an edit of less than 6 characters

Comment: Done. I added diagrams for more details. I want to know how  to remove the dependency between module1 and module3 ?